# Stored procedure throws error, but has no but displays no error message

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that is failing and I get the message

> query completed with errors

but no other details.

If I take the stored procedure and hardcode it as a script with the same parameters, I get get the same result as well. I have tried getting the error values with

```
select 
    ERROR_LINE(), ERROR_NUMBER(),
    ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_SEVERITY
```

but all are blank, null, or zero. Ideas anyone?

Comment: Take the script version, and remove the last half. Still get the error? Then error is in first half. Remove last half of the first half, else did not get the error, so it is in the last half add back the first half. Repeat, narrowing the location by half until location pinpointed.

Comment: It might help to show some code...

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered calling your script or procedure in a TryCatch block? Or, posting some code would help.